# SignaturePadService null on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I just added `SignaturePad.Xamarin.Forms.PCL` from NuGet to my app-project, and when I run `DependencyService.Get<ISignatureService>();` in the Portable library it works fine on Android. But when I run it on iOS, it just returns `null`. What can I have done wrong? 
 
I have the same version of the package (`1.0.0.1`) in both Portable, Android and  iOS.

Do anybody have some suggestions, as I run out of ideas (except of compiling the `SignaturePad.Xamarin.Forms.PCL` project by myself)?

**UPDATE** 

If I set this line (`container.Register<Acr.XamForms.SignaturePad.ISignatureService, Acr.XamForms.SignaturePad.iOS.SignatureService>();`) in `AppDelegate.cs` it works, but shouldn't it be done in the NuGet package?

Answer (score 0):

it's all about custom class so, you have to Adding a SignaturePadView to your iOS app : https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/signature-pad
there is also explain the how to integrate all of this methods and code..